# How is it possible that I don't get an error message when the range is wrong in list slicing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

today I was learning about list slicing in python, and I have a question about the rules by which python "operates/slices" these lists. How is it possible that I don't get an error message when clearly the range is wrong?

```
li=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

li[1:12:1]
  [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Specifying limits out of range simply trims to the end. That is how it works.

Comment: Yeah, it's just the defined semantics. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: Read the documentation.  It's a lot faster than asking StackOverlow.

Comment: Thank you, but what confuses me is :step, how python runs "steps" after int. 6 in this example?

Answer (score 0):

there isnt an index error it just stops at the end:

```
li=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(li[:10])
print(li[:7])
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that, but what confuses me is :step, how python runs "steps" after 6 in this example ?

Comment: i dont know how they algorithmically do it, you would have to check docs/source code for that